# How does synchronizing an object works in java

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-fragments

I'm making a basic android game, I have a fragment that displays the game world. When I open that fragment I create a new thread that just waits until my `NetworkThread` gets the world from the server. Also my `GetWorldThread` is a `static` `Thread` that I only initialize inside the fragment.

This is how my GetWorldThread looks like:

```
synchronized (this)
{
    try 
    {
        Log.d("getWorldThread", "waiting()");
        wait();
    } 
    catch (InterruptedException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }  
}
```

and my `NetworkThread` looks like this

```
if (buffer instanceof World)
{
    synchronized (WorldFragment.getWorldThread)
    {
        World.setWorld(((World) buffer));                
        Log.d("NetworkThread", "notifying World");

        WorldFragment.getWorldThread.notify();
    }

}
```

My code works, but I want to know if there is a way to do this more elegant?.

Comment: Have a look at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/442564/avoid-synchronizedthis-in-java/36692190#36692190

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#wait()) you always should use `wait()` in `while` loop. So your code **may not** work correctly.

More elegant way is to use more high-level abstracnions. For example [Future](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html)  and standart `FutureTask`. This way allows you don't write low-level stuff like loops and therefore to avoid mistakes.

Update: Also note that there are `Condition`s/`Lock`s intended for `wait`/`synchronyzed` substitution as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4916691/2956778). In fact, using `wait()` is obsolete in 2017