# What does "non-block-structured locking" mean?

Tags: java, multithreading, locking, synchronized

I am reading *Java Concurrency in Practice*. In 13.1 Lock and ReentrantLock, it says:

> Why create a new locking mechanism that is so similar to intrinsic locking? Intrinsic locking works fine in most situations but has some functional limitations— it is not possible to interrupt a thread waiting to acquire a lock, or to attempt to acquire a lock without being willing to wait for it forever. Intrinsic locks also must be released in the same block of code in which they are acquired; this simplifies coding and interacts nicely with exception handling, but makes **non-block-structured locking** disciplines impossible.

**What does "non-block-structured locking" mean?** I think it means that you can lock in one method, unlock in another method, like `Lock`, but intrinsic locks must be released in the same block of code in which they are acquired. Am I right?

But the Chinese version of that book translates "block" to "[阻塞](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blocking_(computing))". Is it an error?

Comment: I agree with your interpretation.

Comment: [An answer to "java - Synchronization vs Lock - Stack Overflow"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4202037/5232255) might be helpful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Block structured locking means that the pattern for acquiring and releasing locks mirrors the lexical code structure.  Specifically, a section of code that acquires a lock is also responsible for releasing it; e.g.

```
Lock lock = ...
lock.acquire();
try {
    // do stuff
} finally {
    lock.release();
}
```

The alternative ("non-block-structured locking") simply means that the above constraint does not apply.  You can do things like acquiring a lock in one method and releasing it in a different one.  Or (hypothetically) even pass the lock to another thread to release<sup>1</sup>.  The problem is that this kind of code is a lot harder to get correct, and a lot harder to analyze than the examples like the above.

<sup>1 - Beware.  If you pass acquired locks between threads, you are liable to run into memory anomalies or worse.  Indeed, I'm not even sure that it is legal in Java.</sup>

---

The "block structure" referred to in the quoted text is clearly talking about the lexical structure of the code, as per the Wikipedia article on the topic [Block (programming)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_(programming)).  If the Chinese version of *Java Concurrency in Practice* uses characters that mean "blocking" in the sense of [Blocking (programming)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blocking_(computing)), that is a mistranslation.