# sharing an Object between two thread running two different methods Android Java

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I am new in java Android... I am trying to create two threads (named: `Clean` and `Progress`) that will run two different methods each `method` get the same object `mix`.while `Clean` will run a time consuming `method` that is part of mix's class `(mix.TimeConsumingMethod();)` I want `Progress thread` to monitor the progress of `TimeConsumingMethod()` by checking class variables such as `mix.length` and `mix.framesClean`

in progress I check to see  `mix.length > 0` if not I want `Progress` to wait over here my app crashes and in `log CAT` i get an error of:

```
09-20 10:37:32.773: E/AndroidRuntime(12030): java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException: object not locked by thread before wait()
```

snippet of code invoking both threads:.

```
    mix = new MixMaxMain(); 

    progressThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {

      @Override
      public void run() {
        Progress (mix);
      }
    },"Progress Thread");

    CleanThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            Clean (mix);
        }
    },"Cleaner Thread");

    Log.d("STOP", "SEnding cleanThread AND progress Thread");
    CleanThread.start();
    progressThread.run();
```

snippet of `Clean` running time consuming method:

```
    long time_start = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();        
    mix.Run(Daudio,mu,sigSqr,c);
    long time_end = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
```

snippet of `Progress`:

```
      while(mix.length==0) {try {
      Log.d("Progress", "Length is Zero");
    Thread.sleep(1);//fails here!!
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
} }
  Log.d("Progress", "Clean Has Started");
  int totalProgressLen = (int)(mix.length+0.7*mix.length);

  while(mix.done==false)
  {
      try {
          progressThread.wait(50);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
      progress.setProgress(mix.framsClean*256/totalProgressLen  );
  }
```

Comment: You need to lock the object before calling wait. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/661068/threading-in-java-how-to-lock-an-object

Answer (score 0):

You get the IllegalMonitorStateException if the thread you're calling wait on does not own the lock on the monitor you're calling it on.

To do this, you can surround the wait() call in a synchronized block.  In your case, it would be something like:

```
synchronized(progressThread){
    progressThread.wait(50);
}
```

There is also a way to check for this with the holdsLock(Object obj) method, which will return true only if the current thread holds the monitor lock on the specified object.

For full details, take a look at the [Java Documentation on wait() for an Object](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#wait%28%29).