# Java: How to lock fields of an object

Tags: java, multithreading, object, locking

I'm writing a fast-exchange logic, I have "Channel[ENV.MAX_CHANNELS] fxChannelList" and "ArrayList<Channel> aliveChannelList" for the "Adapter" class.

Now outside the Adapter class (in the GUIManager class) I want to lock down both adapter.fxChannelList and adapter.aliveChannelList when refreshing the GUI, so they will not change during this period (but the exchange logic (elsewhere) still can read them). as I tested the "synchronized" are for code-blocks/methods but not for fields of an object.

Any idea about how to lock a field of an object outside of the class of that object? Or this will cause any problem?

I saw a thread "[Threading in Java: How to lock an object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/661068/threading-in-java-how-to-lock-an-object)" but it seems not the same thing I wanted. Thanks.

Comment: How about synchronizing the methods used to access these lists? Change them to private at the same time.

Comment: Wouldn't that be possible to return an Immutable list from these methods.